# how to get features of vector layer on right click

Tags: extjs, openlayers

I am new in openlayers here i have got the features of vector layer on left click but now 
I need the features of vector layer on right click, is this possible? please help!

My code is:

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vector2,
{multiple:false, click:true , onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect}

); 
map.addControl(selectControl);
selectControl.activate();
```